# JQuery group validation not working and error class not applied

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Jquery group validation not working as expected I have tried the below code in the rule

```
txt_Po: {
    require_from_group: [1, ".txt_Add"]
},
txt_Bdg: {
    require_from_group: [1, ".txt_Add"]
},
txt_St: {
    require_from_group: [1, ".txt_Add"]
},
```

this is my html code

```
<span id="error_message" class="error_msge">
</span>

<form class="Form" id="Form" method="POST">
    <label>P.O.Box</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" class="ipt_Field txt_Add txt_Po" id="txt_Po" name="txt_Po" />
    <br/>
    <label>Building</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" class="ipt_Field txt_Add txt_Bdg" id="txt_Bdg" name="txt_Bdg" />
    <br/>
    <label>Street</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="text" class="ipt_Field txt_Add txt_St" id="txt_St" name="txt_St" />
    <button class="btn-next" id="btn-Next">Next</button>
</form>
```

this is what i am expecting if i click the next button without filling any of the field it should say **kindly enter any one of the field**
if the user starts fill in any one of the field that error message should not be displayed. So I have tried using require from group but this was not working.

here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/54e7tzkt/)

Initially in my js script file I have group valid code

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("require_from_group", function (value, element, options) {
var validator = this;
var minRequired = options[0];
var selector = options[1];
var validOrNot = jQuery(selector, element.form).filter(function () {
    return validator.elementValue(this);
}).length >= minRequired;

    if (this.settings.onkeyup) {
    jQuery(selector, element.form).on({
        'keyup.require_from_group': function (e) {
            jQuery(selector, element.form).valid();
        }
    });
}
return validOrNot;
```

});

is that possible can we **try** like this

```
    $.validator.addMethod("customrule", function (value, element) {
    return (!($(".txt_Po").val() === '') || !($(".txt_Bdg").val() === '') || !($(".txt_St").val() === ''));
```

Now I removed this and checked now the class was working in the group field but the counting was not reduced initally it say's you have three field missed but the user type in any of the field it should not display any error message this was not happening any help please

I am struggling with this current code nothing working out

Thanks & Regards

Comment: any luck for the above question

Answer (score 0):

You are missing http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js.

> Some more methods are provided as add-ons, and are currently included
>   in additional-methods.js in the download package. Not all of them are
>   documented here:
>
> accept – Makes a file upload accept only specified mime-types.
>   extension – Makes the element require a certain file extension.
>   phoneUS – Validate for valid US phone number. require_from_group –
>   Ensures a given number of fields in a group are complete.

As you can read in the documentation
http://jqueryvalidation.org/documentation/

Comment: I have included that but still i am facing the same issue :(

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/54e7tzkt/1/, i just added it to external resources in your jsfiddle, and it works now.

Comment: when i click the next button it was going to forbidden page directly

Comment: So you leave all inputs empty, then press next, and you are being sent to forbidden page ?

Comment: And you're going to http://jsfiddle.net/54e7tzkt/1/ ? I've tested it in Chrome, IE and FireFox. Whenever i press next, without any input, i get the error message.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92124/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-yvo-cilon).

Comment: the problem when i add the additional method jquery plugin in real page it was not working